# Scroll on menus content with container overflow

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, vuetify.js

Please I need help:
How the menus move (how work) with scroll even if the container have overflow scroll in Vuetify.
[image]
In the picture, the menu is moved with button if the container is scrolled.

I want to replicate this in a custom dropdown component.
[image: Overflow behavior in vuetify]

Comment: Please add more details by adding a simple [Vuetify-Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com) demo.